# How to pass sort mode in spring data elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

How to send sort mode in spring data Elasticsearch, similar to below in Elasticsearch.

Elasticsearch Search Query.

```
POST /_search
{
   "query" : {
      "term" : { "product" : "chocolate" }
   },
   "sort" : [
      {"price" : {"order" : "asc", "mode" : "avg"}}
   ]
}
```

I was expecting to see some options like below
searchQuery.withSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("fieldName").order(SortOrder.DESC)).???

Answer (score 1):

You have different ways in Spring Data Elasticsearch to define your search queries (see the documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.2.1/reference/html/#elasticsearch.operations.queries). All these query classes implement the `Query` interface and so have a method `addSort(Sort sort)`

So you basically could add

```
query.addSort(Sort.by("fieldName").descending());
```

However looking at you plain Elasticsearch query, you have specified a `mode = avg`. To use the sort mode you need to define your query as `NativeSearchQuery`by using the Elasticsearch builders:

```
NativeSearchQuery query =
        new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(termQuery("product", "chocolate"))
            .withSort(SortBuilders
                                .fieldSort("price")
                                .order(SortOrder.DESC)
                                .sortMode(SortMode.AVG))
        .build();
```

Comment: Thanks, I am already using  pageable to get the paginated results, and i see there is a sort  option to send inside pageable, can we send sort mode here ?                                  Pageable pageable= PageRequest.of(int page,int size, Sort sort)                                                                                                query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(termQuery("product", "chocolate")).withPageable(pageable)

Comment: No. The `Sort` that's in the `Pageable`comes from the Spring Data Commons project which is used by all the different Spring Data Modules. We cannot add something Elasticsearch specific there.

Comment: Thanks, P.J., another saved soul here...